# dual space of a locally uniform space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The locally uniform space on $\mathbb{R}^N$ collects all functions $f\in L^p_{\textrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with the condition
$$\|f\|_{L_U^p(\mathbb{R}^N)}:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^N}\|f\|_{L^p(B(x,1))}<\infty.$$
I would like to find its dual space. But it seems improbable to write a linear functional $\ell\in L_U^p(\mathbb{R}^N)^*$ as an integral. Clearly 
$\ell(f)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{B(x,1)} f(y)g(y)\mathrm{d}y$ is not linear.

However, as in $L^p$ spaces, I have shown that $$\|f\|_{L_U^p(\mathbb{R}^N)}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^N,\|g\|_{L_U^q(\mathbb{R}^N)}\le 1}\left|\int_{B(x,1)} f(y)g(y)\mathrm{d}y\right|,$$where $p,q$ are dual exponents. So the expression above may be related to $\ell$.

Comment: Every $g\in L^q$ with bounded support (i.e., vanishing outside some large ball) gives a continuous linear functional $\ell(f)=\int_{\mathbb R^N} f(y)g(y)dy$. But probably, the dual is bigger. Where does this space appear?

Comment: Should I use simple or $C_0^\infty$ functions? The paper _Linear parabolic equations in locally uniform spaces_ studies the linear theory of parabolic equations in uniform spaces. In Sec. 4 the author study the locally uniform spaces and their relation with weighted and regular Sobolev spaces. But it seems to be interesting to consider more about this space itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea (written for $N=2$): Decompose the plane $\mathbb R^2$ into squares $Q_{a,b}=[a,a+1)\times [b,b+1)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, and consider the map $$\Phi:L^p_U(\mathbb R^N)\to \ell^\infty(L^p(Q_{a,b})_{a,b\in\mathbb Z}),\; f\mapsto (f|_{Q_{a,b}})_{a,b\in\mathbb Z})$$
where, for Banach spaces $X_i$,  $\ell^\infty((X_i)_{i\in I})=\{ (x_i)_{i\in I}\in \prod_i X_i: \sup\{\|x_i\|_{X_i}:i\in I\}<\infty\}$.

I believe that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism, and on the range you can write down many functionals (with similar definitions, $\ell^1((X_i')_{i\in I})$ embeds into the dual of $\ell^\infty((X_i)_{i\in I})$). However, the dual of $\ell^\infty$ is already an intricate object so that it won't be easy to describe the dual of $\ell^\infty((X_i)_{i\in I})$ in a nice way.